# Self invoking functions javascript to clean up variables on global namespace

Tags: javascript, function, self-invoking-function

Learning javascript and I wanted to get feedback on self invoking functions.

I read that creating global variables is not the way to go.

**This the original**

```
// Footer of page
<script>
    var lat = 51.505 // retrieved from db
    var lon = -0.09  // retrieved from db

    var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);

    L.marker([lat, lon]).addTo(map)
        .bindPopup('You are here.')
        .openPopup();
</script>
```

**Refactored**

```
// Footer of page
<script>
    (function(){
        var createMap = function() {
            var lat = 51.505 // retrieved from db
            var lon = -0.09  // retrieved from db

            var map = L.map('map').setView([lat, lon], 13);

            L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            }).addTo(map);

            L.marker([lat, lon]).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup('You are here.')
                .openPopup();
        }(); // createMap function self invocation
    })(); // anonymous function self invocation
</script>
```

I'm unsure if my refactored version makes sense since I'm creating a function `var createMap` inside an self invocation anonymous function.

I didn't want to cloud up the global namespace with my `lat` & `lon` variables, which is retrieved from the database.

**UPDATE**

Or will the following make more sense. A self invoking anonymous function with the variables and code inside. This will not interfere or add the assigned variables to the global namespace?

```
// Footer of page
<script>
    (function(){
        var lat = 51.505 // retrieved from db
        var lon = -0.09  // retrieved from db

        var map = L.map('map').setView([lat, lon], 13);

        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(map);

        L.marker([lat, lon]).addTo(map)
            .bindPopup('You are here.')
            .openPopup();
    })(); // anonymous function self invocation
</script>
```

Comment: I don't see `var buildMap` anywhere. Do you mean `createMap()`?

Comment: Currently there is no sense in nesting another IIFE. Why do you think you need `createMap`?

Comment: BTW `createMap` is currently `undefined` as it is not referring to the function but to the return of this function.

Comment: Sorry  for the typo, I've updated. buildMap should be createMap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lose the createMap function, there's no need for that, since you're already using the outer **IIFE** (Immediately-Invoked Function Expression). This way you're not polluting the global namespace:

```
(function() {
    var lat = 51.505 // retrieved from db
    var lon = -0.09 // retrieved from db

    var map = L.map('map').setView([lat, lon], 13);

    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);

    L.marker([lat, lon]).addTo(map)
        .bindPopup('You are here.')
        .openPopup();
})(); // anonymous function self invocation
```